# Code Composer Studio '#171 expected a declaration' error

Tags: c

I am receiving an error '#171 expected a declaration' when building my project. Below is the code that seems to be causing the problem. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include "stdbool.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include "inc/hw_i2c.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/i2c.h"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/uart.h"
#include "utils/uartstdio.h"

#include "stdlib.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "time.h"

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x5A
#define SQUARE_WAVE 0
#define TRIANGULAR_WAVE 1
#define SAWTOOTH_WAVE 2
#define SINE_WAVE 3
#define RANDOM_NOISE 4

void InitConsole(void) {

    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PA0_U0RX);
    GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PA1_U0TX);
    SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_UART0);
    UARTClockSourceSet(UART0_BASE, UART_CLOCK_PIOSC);
    GPIOPinTypeUART(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0 | GPIO_PIN_1);
    UARTStdioConfig(0, 115200, 16000000);
}

int i = 0;
int sawTable[1023];

for (i = 0; i < 1023; i++) <--- The error is on this line
    sawTable[i] = i;
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The given code doesn't have any problem.

Comment: @CoolGuy ...except that it's not in a function.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Now that the OP has posted the full code, it seems that you are right. :-)

Comment: @CoolGuy I was thinking that, for once, that *was* the full code!

Comment: Derp. Thanks heaps guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually posted your complete code, you  can't throw statements in the global namespace - when would they run? They need to be in a function. Any introduction to C will tell you that execution starts in `main`.

```
int main (void)
{

    return 0;
}
```

If you're just getting started with C, it would behoove you to learn to write basic console applications on a desktop environment first, before moving to an MCU.

Comment: Thanks heaps. That was a silly mistake...